# Slow network file access on windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems, network-share

We have a really poor business application that uses access databases (I know, fail!) as its back end. There are lots of access db files it uses, all about 4mb in size.

If I copy the files locally to a server, it performs a lot better than if the files are sat on a network smb share, the files are all on the same box, I have just tested by changed c:\files\ to \server\files.

Its probably about 50% faster when pointing locally. The disks are raid 1+0 15k, so they should be fast, running on windows 2008 (not r2) on x86 architecture. There is nothing else on the box, or anyone else accessing it.

Anyone got any ideas why it would be so much slower accessing the files over unc, and any tip I might be able to look into to speed it up?

Cheers
Luke

Comment: Because there is an additional layer, which probably even locally works over tcp/ip, and brings on additional delas, handshakes, configrmations, locks etc., which are not present on direct local access?

Comment: You also don't specify what kind of networking you have in place, if they are on the same network, what kind of switching, what speed switching, etc. But, the bottom line is UNC access will go through the network stack on the both the client and the server and then through the disk I/O stack and has more overhead. So, yes, it will be slower. In theory, you could look at setting up the server as an iSCSI target and mount the disk as an iSCSI volume which might speed up your access. However, I can't recommend you do this without getting more info.

Comment: @Rex He's working with the local machine, so the requests don't even hit the network.

Comment: SMB network access can be effected by DNS, AV, NIC auto-negotiate, etc.  More info needed: IPconfig on server & wkstn, NIC speeds, ping times, is this a domain, errors in Server System event log.